# Using If Statements Instead of Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, if-statement, mocha.js, jestjs

I am a newbie in unit testing (currently learning Jest,) and I can't seem to find a particular reason to use unit testing instead of say an `if` or `else` statement binded with a `console.log()` function. An explanation would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check this out https://medium.com/@bartsis/should-i-test-my-code-546082383501

Comment: OK, log your result. Now write 100 pieces of functionality. Now try to see if any of them is broken. Leave the project for half a year and come back to it - see if anything is broken now. Oh, for extra fun - work with others, too. In 6 month time you'd probably jump from 100 pieces of functionality to 1000. More likely more but let's work with that - see what, if any, is broken.

Comment: You are using Jest to evaluate a lot of things and you'll have to write that functionality yourself, also the tests are run and reported in a bundle

Comment: Do you have automation/CI/CD in place to deploy/manage your application? How would you know tests are failing with console.log() statements to prevent a deployment with errors/bugs?

Comment: This question is an absurd comparison. If statements and unit tests are not just apples and oranges, they're apples and philosophy. You may find [my answer to a related question at SoftwareEngineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/158052/are-unit-tests-really-that-useful/158086#158086) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit testing can be very helpful in testing source code while an application is being built by catching bugs early in the development cycle and easing testers workloads. It's a level of software testing where individual function/method of a software are tested. The purpose is to validate that each function of the software performs as designed.

**Top benefits of Unit Testing:**

1. Make the process agile
2. Quality of code
3. Find software bugs early
4. Facilitates changes & Simplifies Integration
5. Unit testing helps in simplifying the debugging process. If a test fails then only latest changes made in code needs to be debugged.
6. Testing a piece of code forces you to define what that code is responsible for. If you can do this easily, that means the code’s responsibility is well-defined and therefore that it has high cohesion.
7. Since the bugs are found early in unit testing, it helps in reducing the cost of bug fixes. Just imagine the cost of bug found during the later stages of development like during system testing or during acceptance testing.